# Delete every child nodes and keep the comments

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml with the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<attributes>

<!--
    Attribute mapping file defines mapping between AVEVA PID attribute name and        corresponding 
AVEVA NET Characteristic name.-->
<!-- Don't output off-sheet pipe connector characteristics to the EIWM registry file   <drawing>_avngate.xml -->
<attribute class="PIPE CONNECTION FLAGBACKWARD" from="Grid_Reference" output="false"/>
<attribute class="PIPE CONNECTION FLAGBACKWARD" from="PipeId" output="false"/>
<attribute class="All" from="TagSuffix" output="false"/>
</attributes>
```

I want to delete all the child nodes and leave the comments as they are. Here's my code:

```
XmlDocument myxml = new XmlDocument();
myxml.Load(filePath);
XmlNode lastChild;
XmlNode root = myxml.DocumentElement;
while ((lastChild = root.LastChild) != null)
{
    root.RemoveChild(lastChild);
}
myxml.Save(filePath);
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: i successfully deleted all the nodes bt the code also deleted my comment 
I want the comment to as it is

Comment: XmlDocument myxml = new XmlDocument();
            myxml.Load(filePath);
            XmlNode lastChild;
            XmlNode root = myxml.DocumentElement;
            while ((lastChild = root.LastChild) != null)
            {
                root.RemoveChild(lastChild);
            }
            myxml.Save(filePath);

Answer (score 1):

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var root = XElement.Load("Data.xml");
    root.DescendantNodes()
        .Where(x => x.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Comment)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => x.Remove());
    root.Save("Data.xml");
}
```

Result output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<attributes>
  <!--
    Attribute mapping file defines mapping between AVEVA PID attribute name and        corresponding 
AVEVA NET Characteristic name.-->
  <!-- Don't output off-sheet pipe connector characteristics to the EIWM registry file   <drawing>_avngate.xml -->
</attributes>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [XmlNode.NodeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.nodetype.aspx), save the nodes you want to delete, and delete them after.

```
ArrayList<XmlNode> nodesToDelete = new ArrayList<XmlNode>();
while ((lastChild = root.LastChild) != null)
{
    if (lastChild.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Comment)
        nodesToDelete.Add(lastChild);
}

foreach (XmlNode node in nodesToDelete)
{
    if (node.ParentNode != null)
        root.RemoveChild(node);
}
```

Comment: this  will lead to an infinite  loop  if  the first node or a comment between 2 nodes  is a comment type

Comment: this is exactly what is happening in my case

Comment: as of now i have added break statemnet and it is working for my case :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I kinda put the code here for the sake of giving an example. I never do deletion on a list directly inside its loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Here how you  can do  it using Linq to  xml

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement xElement = XElement.Parse(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<attributes>

<!--
    Attribute mapping file defines mapping between AVEVA PID attribute name and        corresponding 
AVEVA NET Characteristic name.-->
<!-- Don't output off-sheet pipe connector characteristics to the EIWM registry file   <drawing>_avngate.xml -->
<attribute class=""PIPE CONNECTION FLAGBACKWARD"" from=""Grid_Reference"" output=""false""/>
<attribute class=""PIPE CONNECTION FLAGBACKWARD"" from=""PipeId"" output=""false""/>
<attribute class=""All"" from=""TagSuffix"" output=""false""/>
</attributes>");
            var fstElement = xElement.FirstNode;
            int i = 0; 
            do
            {
                if (fstElement.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Comment)
                {
                    if (fstElement.Parent != null)
                    {

                        fstElement.Remove();
                        i--;       
                    }
                }
                i++;  

            } while ( i< xElement.Nodes().Count() && (fstElement = xElement.Nodes().ToArray()[i]) != null);


            Console.WriteLine(xElement);


        }
    }
}
```